# What does 'unsigned temp:3' in a struct or union mean?

Tags: c++, c, syntax, bit-fields

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this C++ code mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604968/what-does-this-c-code-mean)

I'm trying to map a C structure to Java using JNA. I came across something that I've never seen.

The `struct` definition is as follows:

```
struct op 
{
    unsigned op_type:9;  //---> what does this mean? 
    unsigned op_opt:1; 
    unsigned op_latefree:1; 
    unsigned op_latefreed:1; 
    unsigned op_attached:1; 
    unsigned op_spare:3; 
    U8 op_flags; 
    U8 op_private;
};
```

You can see some variable being defined like `unsigned op_attached:1` and I'm unsure what would that mean. Would that effect the number of bytes to be allocated for this particular variable?

Comment: Wow, that's completely new to me as well. Nice find!

Comment: Added 'colon' to help it come up in searching.

Comment: The best thing you can do with bit fields is to avoid them. Better use masking & shifting to access groups of bits in integers in a well-defined way.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This construct specifies the length in bits for each field.

The advantage of this is that you can control the `sizeof(op)`, if you're careful. the size of the structure will be the sum of the sizes of the fields inside.

In your case, size of op is 32 bits (that is, `sizeof(op)` is 4).

The size always gets rounded up to the next multiple of 8 for every group of unsigned xxx:yy; construct.

That means:

```
struct A
{
    unsigned a: 4;    //  4 bits
    unsigned b: 4;    // +4 bits, same group, (4+4 is rounded to 8 bits)
    unsigned char c;  // +8 bits
};
//                    sizeof(A) = 2 (16 bits)

struct B
{
    unsigned a: 4;    //  4 bits
    unsigned b: 1;    // +1 bit, same group, (4+1 is rounded to 8 bits)
    unsigned char c;  // +8 bits
    unsigned d: 7;    // + 7 bits
};
//                    sizeof(B) = 3 (4+1 rounded to 8 + 8 + 7 = 23, rounded to 24)
```

I'm not sure I remember this correctly, but I think I got it right.

Comment: Remember kids!  bit fields are compiler dependent, there is no C/C++ standard that specfies that the first 4 bits must be used on the a:4 above.

Comment: Assuming 8 bits per byte is safe. Assuming the compiler won't use padding bits or has one specific byte order, however, isn't.

Comment: C and C++ don't define a byte to be 8 bits.

Comment: It is not multiple of 8，it is multiple a word，a word  is related to the machine， such as 8, 16 or 32 bits

Answer (score 20):

It declares a [bit field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field); the number after the colon gives the length of the field in bits (i.e., how many bits are used to represent it).

Answer (score 6):

```
unsigned op_type:9;
```

Means op_type is an integer variable with 9 bits.

Answer (score 4):

The colon modifier on integral types specifies how many bits the int should take up.