# C++ struct definition

Tags: c++, c, typedef, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ‘unsigned temp:3’ means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950029/what-does-unsigned-temp3-means)

I just found this code in a book *(was used in an example)*

```
typedef struct {
unsigned int A:1;
unsigned int B:1;
unsigned int C:1;
} Stage;
```

What is the meaning of this structure definition? (the `A:1;`)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [What does 'unsigned temp:3' means](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950029/what-does-unsigned-temp3-means).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are C [bitfields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field). In compliant compilers, the combination of A B and C do not occupy more than one `int`. A, B, and C occupy one bit each in the integer.