# How to check if flag in TCP struct is set?

Tags: c, networking, tcp, libpcap, packet-capture

I'm using the pcap C library to read packets. Currently, I use the following to check and see whether a flag in the `struct tcphdr` (this struct is defined in the `netinet/tcp.h` library) is set:

```
struct tcphdr *tcp = ....

if(tcp->th_flags & TH_SYN) {
        //SYN FLAG IS SET?
    }
```

Will this always work for checking if a particular flag is set in the struct? Or is there a better way? Would greatly appreciate any advice/tips :)

Comment: For those confused by the `u_int16_t syn:1;` notation in the definition for `tcphdr`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186008/in-c-what-does-a-colon-mean-inside-a-declaration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks fine to me. `TH_SYN` is a single bit, so that expression will be true (nonzero) if that bit is set in `th_flags`.

Comment: Conversely, if I wish to check that say one of the flags is set but the other isn't, will the following work: if( (tcp->th_flags & TH_SYN) && !(tcp->th_flags & TH_ACK)) ?

Comment: Yes, or you could use if ((tcp->th_flags & (TH_SYN | TH_ACK)) == TH_SYN)