# What does the colon do in this struct definition?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does 'unsigned temp:3' means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950029/what-does-unsigned-temp3-means)

I don't understand this struct definition. It seems illegal to me, but apparently it isn't:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned i:1;
} my_struct;
```

I believe that marking the variable as `unsigned` without a type is the same as marking it as `unsigned int`. However, I'm completely baffled by the colon. What does it do? My guess is that it's some sort of initializer, but I haven't a clue what it means. Off the top of my head, the only place that I'd expect a colon in C is in the ternary operator, which this obviously isn't. So, this appears to be a construct with which I am not familiar. Can anyone explain what the purpose of the colon is in this struct definition? What exactly does the declaration `unsigned i:1;` mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It defines i to be of 1 bit width.
If i:x is given then it defines i to be x bits wide.