# weird struct definition?

Tags: c, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does 'unsigned temp:3' means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950029/what-does-unsigned-temp3-means)

A `struct`'s definition goes like this,

```
typedef struct
{   
    uint32_t length : 8;  
    uint32_t offset : 24;
    uint32_t type : 8;
} A;
```

I haven't seen this kind of definition before, what does it mean by `:8` and `:24`?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4373839/1369241

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's defining bitfields. This tells the compiler that `length` is 8 bits, `offset` is 24 bits and `type` is also 8 bits.

Comment: Then why does it define `length` as `uint32_t`?

Comment: @Alcott That could only work if uint32_t was a typedef for 'unsigned' or 'unsigned int'.

Comment: @EJP, sorry, don't quite understand

Comment: @Alcott Usually the type for bitfields is `unsigned int` (or just `unsigned` or even just `int`). You have to ask the author why he choose to use `uint32_t` (which in most cases is a typedef to `unsigned int` anyway).

Comment: Understand, thanks, @JoachimPileborg.

Answer (score 3):

Refer the following link. They are bit-fields. http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node13.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int uint32_t;

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t length : 8;
    uint32_t offset : 24;
    uint32_t type : 8;
} A;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t length;
    uint32_t offset;
    uint32_t type;
} B;
#pragma pack(pop)

int main()
{
  printf("\n Size of Struct: A:%d   B:%d", sizeof(A), sizeof(B));
  return 0;
}
```

Structure A's size will be 5 Bytes where as B's size will be 12 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

This notation defines bit fields, i.e. the size in number of bits for that structure variable.