# what does this mean in c int a:16;?

Tags: c++, c, programming-languages, annotations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does 'unsigned temp:3' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950029/what-does-unsigned-temp3-mean)

please what does this notation mean

> int a:16;

I found it is code like this and it does compile.

> struct name  {
>        int a:16; }

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a [bitfield](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/bitfields.html).

This particular bitfield doesn't make much sense as you just could use a 16-bit type and you're wasting some space as the bitfield is padded to the size of `int`.

Usually, you are using it for structures that contain elements of bit size:

```
struct {
    unsigned nibble1 : 4;
    unsigned nibble2 : 4;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
struct name { int a:16; }
```

It means `a` is defined as **16-bit** memory space. The remaining bits (16 bits) from `int` can be used to defined another variable, say `b`, like this:

```
struct name { int a:16;  int b:16; }
```

So if `int` is 32-bit (4 bytes), then the memory of one `int` is divided into two variables `a` and `b`.

PS: I'm assuming `sizeof(int)` = 4 bytes, and 1 byte = 8 bits

Answer (score 4):

```
 struct s
    {
     int a:1;
     int b:2;
     int c:7;
    };/*size of structure s is 4 bytes and not 4*3=12 bytes since all share the same space provided by int declaration for the first variable.*/
 struct s1
    {
     char a:1;
     };/*size of struct s1 is 1byte had it been having any more char _var:_val it would have    been the same.*/
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bitfield.

I've never seen a 16 bit bitfield; usually that's a short.

http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node13.html