# What does this ':' operator do in the following C++ code, and why?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does 'unsigned temp:3' means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950029/what-does-unsigned-temp3-means)
>   [what does this mean in c int a:16;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706584/what-does-this-mean-in-c-int-a16)

I came across this `struct` in some C++ code I'm working on.  Can someone explain to me what the colon operator is doing and why one would use it?

```
struct MYMSG
{
    unsigned short  src : 4;
    unsigned short  dst : 11;
    unsigned short  tx    : 1;
};
```

Comment: Number of bits to be allocated.

Comment: So, of the 16 bits in memory, the src field would only use the 4 LSBs?  Or it only allocates 4 bits?

Comment: @bporter Yes src will use only 4 bits, although it may not be the 4 LSB's.  The layout the compiler uses varies by implementation, there is no standard.

Comment: It would have been much easier to close as dupe if there was anyway of searching for ":" - I tried for 5mins and gave up

Comment: @Martin - I agree. I wouldn't have asked the question in the first place had I been able to search for it.  "temp:3" and "a:16" weren't the first search terms to come to mind. :)  Anyway, I'm very grateful for the help I received.  Thanks!

Comment: @bporter - not your fault, in fact it would have been quicker to write the answer than find the dupe. SO has a problem with searching, especially for c/c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented above, it's the number of bits to be used for each field.

```
struct MYMSG
{
    unsigned short  src : 4;   // allows values 0 - 15
    unsigned short  dst : 11;  // allows values 0 - 2047
    unsigned short  tx    : 1; // allows values 0 - 1
};
```

This also has the effect of packing the structure if alignment is turned off.  If this structure is not padded, then a call to `sizeof()` will return 2 (on an 8-bit/byte architecture).

In this case, a single `unsigned short` is allocated, and the bit fields are divided up within that value.  Setting a value outside the range of one of the fields (such as `16` for `src`) will cause an overflow of that particular field, but will not alter the values of any other fields (the value of `dst` will not change).

Take a slightly more obtuse example:

```
struct T
{
   unsigned long val : 4
};
```

This still allocates a full `unsigned long` (32bit on most architectures), but only allows for setting of the first `4` bits giving valid values of `0`-`15`.

Comment: Good follow up question, the answer is a little too complex to have in a comment, so I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  This clears things up quite a bit.