# A question about class definition in C++ " : 1"

Tags: c++, clang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does 'unsigned temp:3' means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950029/what-does-unsigned-temp3-means)

I encountered a problem when I'm reading the code of Clang.

```
class LangOptions {
public:
    unsigned Trigraphs         : 1;  // Trigraphs in source files.
    unsigned BCPLComment       : 1;  // BCPL-style '//' comments.
    ...
};
```

This is the first time I saw the syntax " : 1", what's the " : 1" stands for? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for reminding. Actually it is the same question :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [bitfield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field), which means that the value will only use one bit, instead of 32 (or whatever `sizeof(unsigned) * <bits-per-byte>` is on your platform).

Bitfields are useful for writing compact binary data structures, although they come with some performance cost as the compiler/CPU cannot update a single bit, but needs to perform AND/OR operations when reading/writing a full byte.

Comment: beware with the `*8`, a byte may be more than 8 bits! Thanks for precising the runtime cost :) If I remember correctly there is also a guarantee that arithmetic is performed modulo (2 ^ nb bits) on those fields... but I may be mistaken.

Comment: @Matthieu: Thanks. I've edited to match. Also, won't arithmetic be modulo-2 automatically if you store the result in the requried amount of bits? (or maybe that differs slightly on signed vs. unsigned)

Answer (score 2):

`Trigraphs` and `BCPLComment` use 1 bit only for saving values.

For example,

```
struct S
{
   signed char type : 2;
   signed char num  : 4;
   signed char temp : 2;
};
```

uses only 8 bit of memory. `struct S` may use a single byte or memory.
`sizeof(S)` is 1 for the case of some implementations.
But `type` and `temp` is equal to 0,1,2 or 3. And `num` is 
equal 0,1,2,..., 15 only.

Answer (score 2):

These are bit fields. The "1" is the width in bits.

See the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/struct/bitfield0.html) for an explanation.

Comment: I was going to harp on at you for not linking to the C++ FAQ- but it *doesn't have* an entry for bitfields.