# Colon operator in a variable declaration statement inside struct

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does 'unsigned temp:3' means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950029/what-does-unsigned-temp3-means)

```
struct sample{
    int x    :2;
    char y   :4;
};
```

What does the colon operator do in the above code?

Comment: Don't forget to accept the most useful answer to each of the other questions you've asked.  See the FAQ and the checkmark (tick) by each answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that (a) the signedness of `int x :2;` is implementation-defined (use `signed int` or `unsigned int`), and (b) bit fields of type `char` are non-standard, and there's no real reason not to declare `y` as `unsigned y :4;`.

Answer (score 7):

It is used to specify bit fields.  The size of the field is given in bits.  The layout is compiler-specific.

Comment: Damnit, whenever I'm fact-checking my answer someone always ninja's me to it :(, good job.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - do you mean that the order of `x` and `y` in the following struct is not guaranteed? - `struct layout {int x:2; int y:2};`

Comment: @MByD: I mean that the C standard does not define whether the bits for x are the most significant or least significant bits. It does not define whether those bit fields are stored in 1 byte, or 2 bytes or 4 bytes (or any other number of bytes). It does not define whether the values are signed or unsigned (so you can't tell whether the range of x is -2..+1 or 0..3, or some other range if not using 2's complement arithmetic); likewise for y. All these properties are implementation-defined (so they are known and fixed, but you can't tell what the answer is without looking at the compiler manual).