# : operator in C

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does 'unsigned temp:3' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950029/what-does-unsigned-temp3-mean)

What does ":" operator mean in C. The output of the program below is -1 -1 -3. How?

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct emp
{
    int a:1;
    int b:2;
    int c:4;
} hey;

int main()
{
    hey.a=1;
    hey.b=3;
    hey.c=13;
    printf("%d",hey.a);
    printf("%d",hey.b);
    printf("%d",hey.c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383844/colon-operator-in-a-variable-declaration-statement-inside-struct)?

Answer (score 2):

The colon specifies how much bit width the field has. 
So a is a bit wide, b 2 bits wide and c 4 bits wide.