# In C what does ':' do?

Tags: c, sockets, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does 'unsigned temp:3' means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950029/what-does-unsigned-temp3-means)

I have been trying to learn raw socket programming in C and have come across this:

```
unsigned char      iph_ihl:5, iph_ver:4;
```

I am confused about what the ':' does. Does it even do anything? Or is it just part of the variable's name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking at bitfields.  Those definitions have to be inside a structure, and they mean that `iph_ihl` is a 5-bit field and `iph_ver` is a 4-bit field.

Your example is a bit strange, since an `unsigned char` would be an 8-bit type on most machines, but there are 9 bits worth of fields declared there.

In general bitfields are pretty non-portable, so I would recommend against their use, but you can read more about them [here](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/bitfields.html).

Comment: Can this only be done with chars?

Comment: You can use any integer type.

Comment: @Hudson: You can use `signed int`, `unsigned int`, `int` (which, depending on the implementation, may be treated as signed or unsigned), or `bool`/`_Bool`.  Support for any other types is an implementation-defined extension.

Comment: What's odd about using `unsigned char`, as long as each bit field is 8 bits or less? (Apart from the fact that `unsigned char` bit fields are non-standard.)

Comment: @Keith, it just seems strange, since normally the goal of bitfields is to pack multiple fields into a single integer type's space.  Using them just to create 4- or 5-bit types like in the example is something I haven't seen very often.

Comment: The type used to declare the field pretty much just determines if it's signed or unsigned. I don't understand your middle paragraph at all, the fields don't have to fit in a single variable of type `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 1):

It is bit fields..See [this](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/bitfields.html) good documentation about C bit fields..It is normally used in memory constrained situations (example embedded programming), to tightly pack our usage..

Important point **Bit fields do not have addresses—you can't have pointers to them or arrays of them**

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above mentioned answers, you can take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) for a good introduction on bit fields. One thing to note: bit fields in `c` can be used only on `integer` types. Using bit fields will not only make your program be `non-portable`, it will also be `compiler-dependent`.