# What is meaning of ":" in struct C

Tags: c, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does 'unsigned temp:3' means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950029/what-does-unsigned-temp3-means)

```
  struct Test
  {
      unsigned a : 5;
      unsigned b : 2;
      unsigned c : 1;
      unsigned d : 5;
  };

  Test B;
  printf("%u %u %u %u", B.a, B.b, B.c, B.d); // output: 0 0 0 0
  static struct   Test A = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Could someone explain me what is purpose of `:` in struct, `printf` just outputs `0` so I assume these are not default values, but what they are then?

Also could someone explain me why does `A.a, A.b, A.c, A.d` outputs `1, 2, 1, 4` instead of `1, 2, 3, 4`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That is a [bit field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field).

It basically tells the compiler that `hey, this variable only needs to be x bits wide, so pack the rest of the fields in accordingly, OK`?

Answer (score 2):

These are bit-fields see [this Wikipeadia section on Bitfields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Bit_fields) or this reference about [bit fields](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/bitfields.html)

The number after the `:` indicates how many bits you want to reserve for the identifier on the  left. This allows you to allocate less space than ordinarily would be the case by tightly packing data. You can only do this in `struct`s or `union`s.

Here is a short [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm) on bit-fields.

Comment: Broken link. Be sure to link to the right section of the article next  time.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Bit_fields

Answer (score 0):

Easy explanation: You specify how many bits your variable should be. (You can't specify more bits than the original size of the type.)

**EDIT:** Your third variable only prints 1 because it has only `1 bit` to store its data. So the value can only be `0` or `1`. The decimal value `3` is represented by `11` in binary format. So no matter which of the bits gets truncated, you will end up with a `1` stored in your variable.