# Plain-Ole-C. How do I interpret this c-struct

Tags: c, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does 'unsigned temp:3' means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950029/what-does-unsigned-temp3-means)

I am writing an iOS app and have to deal with some legacy plain ole C:

```
typedef struct {
    int32_t tid;
    int32_t pos;
    uint32_t bin:16, qual:8, l_qname:8;
    uint32_t flag:16, n_cigar:16;
    int32_t l_qseq;
    int32_t mtid;
    int32_t mpos;
    int32_t isize;
} bam1_core_t;
```

My question involves the line `uint32_t bin:16, qual:8, l_qname:8;` can someone please tell me how to access these fields that appear to me some sort of bit-vector sub-field of a 32-bit int.

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: That's exactly what they are.

Comment: It's a bit field, and ironically, this question was asked just a little while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197931/what-is-meaning-of-in-struct-c/11197966#11197966

Comment: Wow. Should have checked first. RTFSO as it were. Closing down.

Answer (score 4):

These are bit-fields. You access them like any other field in a structure. The number after the colon defines the number of bits used to store that field. For example, the `qual:8` means `qual` can hold values (only) from 0 to 255.

I should add that `:0`  is special -- it means no more bit-fields should be allocated from the current item (int, uint32_t, etc.) -- the next bit field will come from a new underlying storage unit.

Answer (score 2):

These are [bit-fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Bit_fields) and you refer to them like this:

`bam1_core_t.bin` or `bam1_core_t.qual` etc.

These bit-fields allow you to pack data more tightly. The number to the right of the `:` specifies how many bits should be allocated to the location associated with the identifier on the left.

The only place you'll see this in C are in `struct`s or `union`s.