# What is this C syntax?

Tags: c, bit-fields

I have no idea what to call it, so I have no idea how to search for it.

`unsigned int odd : 1;`

Edit:

To elaborate, it comes from this snippet:

```
struct bitField {
    unsigned int odd : 1;
    unsigned int padding: 15; // to round out to 16 bits
};
```

I gather this involves bits, but I'm still not all the way understanding.

Comment: Please search the site first before asking, and also please give it a better title. Looking at your question I have plenty of "related" question in the right column, that show that it would have been easy to find something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does 'unsigned temp:3' mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950029/what-does-unsigned-temp3-mean)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are bitfields. `odd` and `padding` will be stored in one `unsigned int` (16 bit) where `odd` will occupy the lowest bit, and `padding` the upper 15 bit of the `unsigned int`.

Comment: Wow, a programmer named his struct appropriately?? I ruled out the possibility and didn't bother searching the term *bitfield*.

Comment: @Aerovistae Actually the name is “bit-field”, but the programmer can be excused for omitting the dash in his struct name.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bitfield - Check the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/struct/bitfield0.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's:

- 1 bit of "odd" (e.g. 1)
- 15 bits of "padding" (e.g. 0000000000000001)
- and (potentially) whatever other bits round out the `unsigned int`. In modern 32-bit platforms where this is 32 bits, you'll see another 16 0s in memory (but not in the struct). (In this case `sizeof` returns 4)

Bitfields can save memory but potentially add instructions to computations. In some cases compilers may ignore your bitfield settings. You can't make any assumptions about how the compiler will choose to actually lay out your bit field, and it can depend on the endianness of your platform.

The main thing I use bitfields for is when I know I will be doing a lot of copying of the data, and not necessarily a lot of computation on or reference of the specific fields in the bit field.