# What does respawn:1 mean in c?

Tags: c, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does this mean in c int a:16; ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706584/what-does-this-mean-in-c-int-a16)

What does the `:1` mean here:

```
...
unsigned respawn:1;
unsigned just_respawn:1;
unsigned detached:1;
unsigned exiting:1;
unsigned exited:1;
} ngx_process_t;
```

Comment: Many duplicates on SO already, e.g. [what does this mean in c int a:16; ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706584/what-does-this-mean-in-c-int-a16); [Colons after variable name on C code.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983943/colons-after-variable-name-on-c-code); [What does 'unsigned temp:3' means](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950029/what-does-unsigned-temp3-means).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

respawn is a bitfield which is 1 bit wide, so it can take on the value of 0 or 1.

Comment: then what's `unsigned ` there for?

Comment: bit-fields, like ints, can be signed or unsigned. In the case of a 1-bit field, you want it to be unsigned because you don't have room for a sign bit.

Comment: Actually, I suppose you could have a signed int bit field which is 1 bit wide. It could store either a -1 or 0.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a [bit field](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node13.html#SECTION001320000000000000000) in a `struct` (the header you omitted).  The `:1` means "1 bit wide", so in your case, they're all booleans.  The compiler is supposed to optimize their space usage by packing many of them per byte.

Comment: @JB,then what's `unsigned ` there for?

Comment: @compile-fan: it's the field's type.  Fields are integers, they can be either signed or unsigned. (this would mostly make sense for fields wider than 1).