# What does this construction means?

Tags: c++

```
class Test 
{

    struct
    {
      unsigned has_some_value1: 1;
      unsigned has_some_value2: 1;
    } info;
};
```

What does  `unsigned has_some_value1: 1;` means?

Should be the following statement true:  `sizoef(type) == bit1 + ... + bitn` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604968/what-does-this-c-code-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called "bit fields". `has_some_value1` occupies one bit. `has_some_value2` also occupies one bit—maybe the *next* physical bit in memory, or maybe not (depends how your compiler is configured to handle bit field alignment).

Comment: sizeof() will obviously, at a very minimum, round up the size to the next whole number of *bytes* after adding up the bit widths and dividing by 8. But it may also be more, due to architecture- and compiler-specific struct alignment issues.

Answer (score 1):

A bitfield in a nonstatic instance of an un-named struct called "info", which is itself a member of "Test".