# what is C++ bool myVar : 1?

Tags: c++

I'm looking at [this](https://github.com/openrisc/llvm-or1k/blob/master/include/llvm/CodeGen/ScheduleDAG.h#L287) file. 
The code looks like the following

```
bool isVRegCycle : 1;
```

The only time I've seen something like this before is in C in `structs` when bitfields are used. How do I interpret this in C++?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The same as in C, it is a bitfield interpreted as `bool`.

Comment: It's a bitfield. C++ is superset of C (almost), so I'm not sure why you'd think this was any different.

Comment: @rlbond I thought it was different because it is used with bool. I only saw it used in C with integers.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604968/what-does-a-colon-in-a-struct-declaration-mean-such-as-1-7-16-or-32

Answer (score 1):

It's the same in C++, a bit-field.

C++ has nearly all of C as a subset.

The difference are however enough that it's best to treat them as two different languages.

Comment: Let's talk packing. Does each bool myVar : 1 occupy a single byte or 8 of those occupy a byte?

Comment: @flashburn: 8 of those in sequence, on an 8-bit byte machine, should ideally occupy one byte. But I think it depends on the compiler and options, i.e. not guaranteed (just allowed) by the standard.