# What does it means int i:3 in variable assignment?

Tags: c, struct, operators, variable-assignment, bit-fields

I'm trying to understand the following code in C:

```
struct values{
  int i:3;
  int j:3;
  int k:2;
};

int main(){
    struct values v = {-6,2,5};
    printf("%d %d %d", v.i,v.j,v.k);
}
```

This code produces the following output:

```
2 2 1
```

I'm trying to understand what does it mean the assignment for `int` values used inside the struct **i.e.:** `int i:3` ?

I know that **:** is not an operator. So what does it do?
Also, can someone explain how this output is achieved?

Thanks very much!

Comment: its declaring a bit-field, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Comment: Why do you call it "assignment"? Where do you see any similarity to "assignment" here?

Comment: My mistake calling it assignement. It was my first impression but I really had no idea of the meaning. Thanks for giving me the right place to look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers specifies the length in bits for each field.

Hence `i` and `j` are represented in 3 bits while `k` in 2 bits.

By the way this is question is clearly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604968/what-does-a-colon-in-a-struct-declaration-mean-such-as-1-7-16-or-3) and there's a very good answer I suggest you to read.

Comment: downvoter can let me know why?

Comment: It wasn't me but perhaps the downvoter though you should have voted to close as a duplicate *instead of* posting an answer.

Comment: Oh well, i've actually flagged the question as duplicate, anyhow I thought that it could be helpful for OP to have a direct hint..